# Get multiple previous rows data, where dimension is the same and dates are not skipped in python? (Best Performance)

Tags: python, pandas

How do I use data from the previous rows to calculate a column, where it only looks at another column for grouping, and skips if not enough rows can be found?

Column 'Goal' = Sum of Current Quarter 'Value1' and Previous two quarters 'Value1', but if a quarter is missing (An approach would be no data is available for 100+ days) then that would not be valid.

Total DataSet is 250,000 rows, so im looking for the best performance to do this, I was able to achieve the result with two If statements and then some boolean math per row, but it was very slow.

Input:

```
    Dimension       Date  Value1  Value2
0           1 2002-04-30      10      20
1           1 2002-01-31      10      20
2           1 2001-10-31      10      20
3           1 2001-07-31      10      20
4           1 2001-04-30      10      20
5           1 2001-01-31      10      20
6           1 2000-10-31      10      20
7           2 2002-04-29      10      20
8           2 2002-01-31      10      20
9           2 2001-10-31      10      20
10          2 2001-07-31      10      20
11          2 2001-04-30      10      20
12          2 2001-01-31      10      20
13          2 2000-10-31      10      20
14          3 2002-04-30      10      20
15          3 2002-01-31      10      20
16          3 2001-10-31      10      20
17          3 2001-07-31      10      20
18          3 2001-01-31      10      20
19          3 2001-10-31      10      20
```

Output:

```
    Dimension       Date  Value1  Value2  Goal
0           1 2002-04-30      10      20    30
1           1 2002-01-31      10      20    30
2           1 2001-10-31      10      20    30
3           1 2001-07-31      10      20    30
4           1 2001-04-30      10      20    30
5           1 2001-01-31      10      20    NA <- Not Enough Previous Rows for Dimension
6           1 2000-10-31      10      20    NA <- Not Enough Previous Rows for Dimension
7           2 2002-04-29      10      20    30 <- Data posted a day early, still in the 100 day range
8           2 2002-01-31      10      20    30
9           2 2001-10-31      10      20    30
10          2 2001-07-31      10      20    30
11          2 2001-04-30      10      20    30
12          2 2001-01-31      10      20    NA <- Not Enough Previous Rows for Dimension
13          2 2000-10-31      10      20    NA <- Not Enough Previous Rows for Dimension
14          3 2002-04-30      10      20    30
15          3 2002-01-31      10      20    30
16          3 2001-10-31      10      20    NA <- Data for 2001-04-31 was missing. Gap Over 100 days between 07-31 & 01-31
17          3 2001-07-31      10      20    NA <- Data for 2001-04-31 was missing. Gap Over 100 days.
18          3 2001-01-31      10      20    NA <- Not Enough Previous Rows for Dimension
19          3 2000-10-31      10      20    NA <- Not Enough Previous Rows for Dimension
```

Input CSV

```
Dimension,Date,Value1,Value2
1,4/30/2002,10,20
1,1/31/2002,10,20
1,10/31/2001,10,20
1,7/31/2001,10,20
1,4/30/2001,10,20
1,1/31/2001,10,20
1,10/31/2000,10,20
2,4/30/2002,10,20
2,1/31/2002,10,20
2,10/31/2001,10,20
2,7/31/2001,10,20
2,4/30/2001,10,20
2,1/31/2001,10,20
2,10/31/2000,10,20
3,4/30/2002,10,20
3,1/31/2002,10,20
3,10/31/2001,10,20
3,7/31/2001,10,20
3,1/31/2001,10,20
3,10/31/2001,10,20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my go at it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',index_col = ['Date','Dimension'], parse_dates=True)
df_unstacked = df.unstack('Dimension')
df_goal_unstacked =  df_unstacked.rolling(window=3, min_periods = 3).sum()
df_goal_stacked = df_goal_unstacked.stack('Dimension')
df['Goal'] = df_goal_stacked['Value1']

print df
```

yields:

```
                      Value1  Value2  Goal
Date       Dimension                      
2002-04-30 1              10      20  30.0
2002-01-31 1              10      20  30.0
2001-10-31 1              10      20  30.0
2001-07-31 1              10      20  30.0
2001-04-30 1              10      20  30.0
2001-01-31 1              10      20   NaN
2000-10-31 1              10      20   NaN
2002-04-30 2              10      20  30.0
2002-01-31 2              10      20  30.0
2001-10-31 2              10      20  30.0
2001-07-31 2              10      20  30.0
2001-04-30 2              10      20  30.0
2001-01-31 2              10      20   NaN
2000-10-31 2              10      20   NaN
2002-04-30 3              10      20  30.0
2002-01-31 3              10      20  30.0
2001-10-31 3              10      20   NaN
2001-07-31 3              10      20   NaN
2001-01-31 3              10      20   NaN
2000-10-31 3              10      20   NaN
```

BTW. I assumed the last line of your csv has a typo and should have year 2000 instead of year 2001. Otherwise it is a duplicate entry.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df = df.sort_values(['Dimension', 'Date'])
df = df.set_index('Date')
df['Date2'] = df.index.copy().astype(int)

df['goal_mult'] = df.groupby('Dimension')['Date2']\
                    .transform(lambda x: x.rolling('190D')\
                    .apply(lambda x: 1 if np.unique(x).size > 2 else np.nan))

df['goal'] = (df['Value1'] + df['Value2']) * df['goal_mult']

            Dimension  Value1  Value2                Date2  goal_mult  goal
Date                                                                       
2000-10-31          1      10      20   972950400000000000        NaN   NaN
2001-01-31          1      10      20   980899200000000000        NaN   NaN
2001-04-30          1      10      20   988588800000000000        1.0  30.0
2001-07-31          1      10      20   996537600000000000        1.0  30.0
2001-10-31          1      10      20  1004486400000000000        1.0  30.0
2002-01-31          1      10      20  1012435200000000000        1.0  30.0
2002-04-30          1      10      20  1020124800000000000        1.0  30.0
2000-10-31          2      10      20   972950400000000000        NaN   NaN
2001-01-31          2      10      20   980899200000000000        NaN   NaN
2001-04-30          2      10      20   988588800000000000        1.0  30.0
2001-07-31          2      10      20   996537600000000000        1.0  30.0
2001-10-31          2      10      20  1004486400000000000        1.0  30.0
2002-01-31          2      10      20  1012435200000000000        1.0  30.0
2002-04-30          2      10      20  1020124800000000000        1.0  30.0
2001-01-31          3      10      20   980899200000000000        NaN   NaN
2001-07-31          3      10      20   996537600000000000        NaN   NaN
2001-10-31          3      10      20  1004486400000000000        NaN   NaN
2001-10-31          3      10      20  1004486400000000000        NaN   NaN
2002-01-31          3      10      20  1012435200000000000        1.0  30.0
2002-04-30          3      10      20  1020124800000000000        1.0  30.0
```